# Regex C# for ~ delimited text file

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match 190 in the following ~ delimited text file

```
GPSE~21~ADVANCED PAVING~P.O. BOX 12847~Ogden~UT~84201~190~12/5/2008~OVER 60~2/3/2009~112458~12/5/2008~12/5/2008~5176~WESTERN GAS PROCESSOR, GRANGER~MOUNTAIN GAS PLANT~GRANGER~WY~82934~7533~TESORO REFINING~474 WEST 900 NORTH~SALT LAKE CITY~UT~841031494~BUT~Freight~5000~0.0577~288.5~360.63
GPSE~21~ADVANCED PAVING~P.O. BOX 12847~Ogden~UT~84201~190~12/5/2008~OVER 60~2/3/2009~~12/5/2008~12/5/2008~~~~~~~~~~~~~~FUEL SURCHARGE~288.5~0.25~72.13~360.63
```

there are basically 2 lines with number 190. I wantto use regex to match "190". I am new with regex and I dunno How i can match this. Can anyone help me with creating a regular expression to match "190" in both the lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you essentially only need to get the 8th field, you won't need regular expressions at all.

This little snippet should do the trick (nicely wrapped in a method for easy usage - I even did the error handling part for you):

```
public string GetInvoiceNumber(string line)
{
    if(line == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("line");
    }

    var res = line.Split('~');

    if(res.Length < 8)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The given line of text does not contain an invoice number!", "line");
    }

    return res[7];
}
```

Comment: This is long time done.. Thanks anyways.. I dunno how to close this.

Comment: You could just mark one of these answers as correct by clicking on the tickmark icon on the left of that particular post. And I would have posted this anyways, since the other answers are horrible, considering the difference between answering the question and _answering_ it ;)

Answer (score 0):

A regex to match "190" between ~ symbols would be:

```
/~190~/
```

If you're trying to match the eighth field in your ~ delimited file, split on ~, then take the eighth field. In Perl, for example:

```
my @fields = split /~/, $string;
my $wanted = $fields[7];
```

Your question is fairly ambiguous as to what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I want to match 190 in both lines. 190 is actually an invoice number value. It can change in each line like it can be a string value like "EA123" or 193 or 186 or something smiliar. So basically as u said i need to fine 8th field.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Ops! Now I realized you want the regex in C#. Omit this message in that case.

One solution with a 'Perl' regular expression. It matches any character except '~' followed by '~'. And that process seven times. After this, it selects all characters until it finds the first '~' (which would be the eighth field of your file). Parentheses saves that content in variable '$1'.

```
/(?:[^~]*~){7}([^~]*)/
```

**A test**:

Content of *script.pl*

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while ( <DATA> ) {
        print qq[$1\n] if m/(?:[^~]*~){7}([^~]*)/;
}

__DATA__                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
GPSE~21~ADVANCED PAVING~P.O. BOX 12847~Ogden~UT~84201~190~12/5/2008~OVER 60~2/3/2009~112458~12/5/2008~12/5/2008~5176~WESTERN GAS PROCESSOR, GRANGER~MOUNTAIN GAS PLANT~GRANGER~WY~82934~7533~TESORO REFINING~474 WEST 900 NORTH~SALT LAKE CITY~UT~841031494~BUT~Freight~5000~0.0577~288.5~360.63                                                                                                                                                                                          
GPSE~21~ADVANCED PAVING~P.O. BOX 12847~Ogden~UT~84201~190~12/5/2008~OVER 60~2/3/2009~~12/5/2008~12/5/2008~~~~~~~~~~~~~~FUEL SURCHARGE~288.5~0.25~72.13~360.63
```

Running the script:

```
perl script.pl
```

And result:

```
190
190
```

Comment: Thanks but that /(?:[^~]*~){7}([^~]*)/ returned more than one matching words.

Comment: Drop the `/`s and you can use it in C#.